# XMonad how can I focus on a particular window by name / class name?

Tags: xmonad

How can I focus on a particular application type like Firefox for example?

I want to bind this to a key binding - so this would not be done interactively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module WindowFinder where

import XMonad
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import Control.Monad
import Data.Bool  (bool)

findWindows :: String -> X [Window]
findWindows name = do
  withWindowSet $ (\ws -> do
    forM (W.allWindows ws)
      (\w -> do
            s <- withDisplay $ \d -> fmap resClass . liftIO $ getClassHint d w
            return $ bool [] [w] (s == name) :: X [Window]
      ) >>= return . join
    )
```

And within a `X ()` context:

```
        win' <- findWindows "Chromium"
        when (length win' > 0)
          (windows $ W.focusWindow $ head win')
```

The above seems to behave in quite a useful manner when there are multiple windows. The behavior seems to be, the first window returned is either the window currently open on the workspace, or the last interacted window of that applicaiton type.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take a look on [XMonad-Actions-WindowGo](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.15/docs/XMonad-Actions-WindowGo.html), especially on `raiseNextMaybe` / `raiseNext` / `runOrRaise`

Something like

```
((modMask x .|. mod1Mask, xK_BackSpace), raiseNextMaybe (spawn "google-chrome --profile-directory='Default' --app='https://www.evernote.com/Home.action'") (appName =? "www.evernote.com__Home.action"))
```

Also, take a look on `xprop` application (it allows to get window class and other attributes)